# Convert JavaScript Object to string

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object

I'm working on a project in Angular 8 in which I post values from a textArea and get an Object as the following from an API : [API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp0AJ.png) , I'm trying to access "raisonSociale" but I can't find a way to do it

Here's my http.post :

```
postResponse: any;

postRefs(){
return this.httpClient.post(this.url,this.datas)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data)
      const parsed = JSON.stringify(data)
      return this.postResponse = parsed;
    },
  );
 }
```

So, I store the response from POST in postReponse and try to render in my html file

```
         <tr>
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{postResponse.crossPart.all}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{postResponse}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{postResponse}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{postResponse}}</td>
        </tr>
```

But in my HTML it render as the following : [HTML result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU1dY.png)

**What I've tried :**

I tried to without using const parsed :

```
postRefs(){
return this.httpClient.post(this.url,this.datas)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data)
      JSON.stringify(data)
      return this.postResponse = data;
    },
  );
}
```

The above returns me [Object Object] : [Object result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35ENd.png)

Thank's for your time and your help in advance.

**EDIT :**

Thank you all for the answers!

@DmytroHuz solution made it work like a charm, here's what needed to be done :

```
        <tr *ngFor="let item of postResponse.crossPart.found">
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{item.articleSociete}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{item.raisonSociale}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{postResponse}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{postResponse}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: you are getting an array of objects, so you should loop it in the `component.html` using `*ngFor`

Comment: You are trying to set in your HTML object that you put into `postResponse` variable. If you need some particular value from your response, you need to call it in a way like: `postResponse.crossPart.all[0].articleSI`

Comment: show output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: you can try `{{ postResponse | json }}`

Comment: @ram12393 How should I do that ? It tells me that *ngFor isn't a know propertie of <td>

Comment: @DmytroHuz It still renders as [ Object Object ]

Comment: have look on https://alligator.io/angular/ngfor-directive/

Comment: @AdritaSharma I edited the post with the full output

Comment: @VadimKhamzin it renders as the full JSON output, not only the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set in your HTML object that you put into `postResponse` variable. If you need some particular value from your response, you need to call it in a way like: `postResponse.crossPart.all[0].raisonSociale`. Or you can use `*ngFor` for `postResponse.crossPart.all`

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of postResponse.crossPart.all>
    <td *ngIf="postResponse">{{item.raisonSociale}</td>
          ...
</tr>
```

Comment: This is it! It renders now properly! Thank's alot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

postResponse is an object, so when you access it in the HTML, it prints as object.

postResponse.crossPart.all is an array, so again it prints as object.

**Specify the object property or loop in case of array to print primitive values**